# JS Changing Classes issue

Tags: javascript, sockets

I'm using API sockets to update the market data.

and I want to classes change when the price goes up and down,
my first class (_class) is working successfully,
second class (_class2) is working at the start by changing to UP (pump) but it won't get back to down (dump) when the price goes down just like the first class. I'm in a bit of confusion coz I'm not so experienced at js.
can anyone tell me where I am mistaken?

```
window.updateMarkets = function (data) {
    if (data.coin != undefined) {
        var coin = 'BTC_' + data.coin;
        var coin_data = data.msg;
        var _coinTable = $('#coins-info-table');
        var row = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin);
        price = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin + " .price");
        change = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin + " .change");
        volume = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin + " .volume");
        capital = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin + " .market_capital");
        supply = _coinTable.find("tr#" + coin + " .supply");
        _price = formatter.format(coin_data.price);
        previous_price = $(price).data('usd');
        _class = coin_data.cap24hrChange >= 0 ? 'increment' : 'decrement';
        _class2 = coin_data.cap24hrChange >= 0 ? 'pump' :'dump';
        if (coin_data.cap24hrChange >= 0.0) {
            $(price).html(_price).removeClass().addClass(_class + ' price').data("usd", _price);
        } else {
            $(price).html(_price).removeClass().addClass(_class + ' price').data("usd", _price);
        }
        if (coin_data.cap24hrChange >= 0.0) {
            $(price).html(_price).removeClass().addClass(_class2 + ' price').data("usd", _price);
        } else {
            $(price).html(_price).removeClass().addClass(_class2 + ' price').data("usd", _price);
        }

        $(volume).html(formatter.format(coin_data.volume));
        $(capital).html(formatter.format(coin_data.mktcap));
        $(supply).html(coin_data.supply);



        if (_price !== previous_price) {
            _class = previous_price < _price ? 'increment' : 'decrement';
            _class2 = previous_price < _price ? 'pump' : 'dump';
            $(row).addClass(_class);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(row).removeClass('increment decrement');
            }, 300);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you setting  _class2 anywhere to DOM as you did _class?

Comment: @G_S yes. It changes to 'pump' or 'dump' by the data  at the first load up but it won't change back

Comment: This condition - `if (coin_data.cap24hrChange >= 0.0)` is using `_class2`, if so check the `coin_data.cap24hrChange` value when price goes down.

Comment: @NnN tried that even set up the value to -1 but didn't work. the interesting part is first class (_class) is working with the same condition and it goes up and down

Comment: provide sample `html` structure, it will be helpful to figure out!

Comment: <td class="increment pump change">%' . $coin['cap24hrChange'] . '</td>

Comment: this is the td.. class increment works but the pump won't